# Median household income for each county in Maryland

Tags: curated-data, finance, geography, wolfram-alpha-queries

I found that Wolfram|Alpha knows the median household income for every county in the US. I wanted to get a list of all counties in Maryland, and the median income in each county. The only way I could find to do that is to first query for a list of counties in Maryland. After that I queried each county individually. That gave me lots of data on each county, but I only care about median household income. This approach required 25 queries. Is there an easier way using Wolfram|Alpha? Also, how would I learn how to this in *Mathematica* without a Wolfram|Alpha query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way using WolframAlpha:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using Mathematica (v10)

```
Reverse[SortBy[
         EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision","USCountiesMaryland"][{"Name","MedianHouseholdIncome"}], 
         Last]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: How would one do this for racial makeup, a table of white, black, Native American, etc.?

Comment: I don't think Wolfram has that information.  See `EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
  "MedianHouseholdIncome"]["Qualifiers"]` vs `EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Population"]["Qualifiers"]`

Answer (score 6):

```
data = WolframAlpha["median income in Maryland counties", {{"PropertyRanking:ACSData",  1}, 
                    "ComputableData"}];

data // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Can we infer anything about where lobbyists reside?

Answer (score 1):

We can learn the syntax though <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> `counties of maryland median household income`, which gives

```
EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "USCountiesMaryland"][EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "MedianHouseholdIncome"]]
```

[image]

We can adapt this piece of generated code to return the counties too.

```
EntityValue[
  EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "USCountiesMaryland"], 
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "MedianHouseholdIncome"],
  "EntityAssociation"
]
```

[image]